# Using jQuery To Search .CSV File

Tags: jquery, html

I’m completely new to jQuery so apologies for any obvious errors.

I have a .CSV file with headings and data laid out as:

Order Number, Stock Status, Quantity, Comments, Date
1234567, In Stock, 15, All in Red, 15/08/2012
1234568, Out of Stock, 203, Leave with neighbour, 21/08/2012
1234569, On Order, 20, Chrome finish, 17/08/2012
1234570, Other, 140, Wooden garment, 01/09/2012

I have a HTML page with 4 buttons (correspond with Stock Status):

In Stock,
Out of Stock,
On Order,
Other,

What I am trying to do is when I click one of the above, my code goes away, searches for all records that match on Stock Status column and returns Order Number, Quantity and Comments.

Code so far:

```
var allText =[];
var allTextLines = [];
var Lines = [];
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();

txtFile.open("GET", "file://C:/data.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 allText = txtFile.responseText;
 allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
};

// On opening the site, show the loading icon and GIF.
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Outline").hide();
$("#loadingTable").delay(1000).hide(0);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) { processData(data); }     
})
alert("0.2")
});

function showSLAMenus() {
$("#Outline").show();
};

$("#OutOfStock").click(function() {
alert("OutOfStock search")
// returns Order Number, Quantity and Comments for items Out of Stock
});

$("#InStock").click(function() {
alert("InStock search")
// returns Order Number, Quantity and Comments for items In Stock
});

$("#Other").click(function () {
alert("Other search")
// returns Order Number, Quantity and Comments for items Other
});

function processData(allText) {
alert("1")
var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/); 
var headers = allTextLines[0].split(','); 
var lines = []; 

for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) { 
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(','); 
    if (data.length == headers.length) { 

        var tarr = []; 
        for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) { 
            tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]); 
        } 
        lines.push(tarr); 
    } 
} 
alert(lines); 
}
```

**My second attempt:**

```
// On opening the site, show the loading icon and GIF.
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Outline").hide();
$("#loadingTable").delay(1000).hide(0);
var data = []; // Empty array in global scope where we will store your data

// Your ajax call to get the data and store it in the var above
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) { processData(data); }
})
});

function showSLAMenus() {
$("#Outline").show();
};

setTimeout(showSLAMenus, 1001);

$("#Other").click(function () {
alert("Other1")
// An example search call
var output = searchData(data, "Other");

alert("Other2")

// Dump out the results of our search
for (var i in output) {
    $("div#output").html(output[i] + "<br>");
}
});

// Main function to process the data into an array
function processData(allText) {
var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
var lines = [];

for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    if (data.length == headers.length) {

        var tarr = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            tarr.push(headers[j] + ":" + data[j]);
        }
        lines.push(tarr);
    }
    //alert(lines);
}
return lines; // Returns the data you need, to be stored in our variable 
}

// A search function using the jQuery inArray method
// - matches the data position in the array and returns a new array of matched data
function searchData(data, search) {
alert("searchData Called")
// Create a temp array to store the found data
var tempArray = [];

// Loop through the data to see if each array has the search term we need
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pos = $.inArray(search, data[i]);

    // Add found data to the array
    if (pos !== -1) {
        tempArray.push(data[i]);
    }
}

// Return the array of matched data
return tempArray;
}
```

Hi, thanks. Your code in jsFiddle seems to be working. However, looking at my code, when clicking the Other button

```
alert("Other1")
// An example search call
var output = searchData(data, "Other");
alert("Other2")
```

Alert Other1 is displayed, but it fails to call searchData i believe.

Do i need to still have

```
txtFile.open("GET", "file://C:/data.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   allText = txtFile.responseText;
   allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
};
```

In my code???

Thanks.

Comment: Code suggested below not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nearly there. The best thing to do is use the jQuery `$.inArray` method to match the lines in the array with the data you're after. You'll only need one search function which returns the data you're after as a new array. Here's an example - **EDIT**: http://jsfiddle.net/gNTWk/1/

How does that affect your code? Added below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var data = []; // Empty array in global scope where we will store your data
    
    // Your ajax call to get the data and store it in the var above
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            data = processData(data);
        }     
    });

    // Your main function to process the data into an array
    function processData(allText) {
        alert("1")
        var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/); 
        var headers = allTextLines[0].split(','); 
        var lines = []; 
    
        for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) { 
            var data = allTextLines[i].split(','); 
            if (data.length == headers.length) { 
    
                var tarr = []; 
                for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) { 
                    tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]); 
                } 
                lines.push(tarr); 
            } 
        } 
        return lines; // Returns the data you need, to be stored in our variable 
    }


    // A search function using the jQuery inArray method
    // - matches the data position in the array and returns a new array of matched data
    function searchData(data, search){
        // Create a temp array to store the found data
        var tempArray = [];
        
        // Loop through the data to see if each array has the search term we need
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var pos = $.inArray(search, data[i]);
            
            // Add found data to the array
            if(pos !== -1){
                tempArray.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
        
        // Return the array of matched data
        return tempArray;
    }


    // An example search call
    var output = searchData(data, "Other");

    // EDITED OUTPUT LOOP    
    for(i=0; i<output.length; i++){
        $("div#output").append(output[i] + "<br>");
    }

 });
```

**EDIT:**
Apologies the `searchData` function was fine. It was just the output loop that was wrong. Above code should work fine now. Edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gNTWk/1/

Comment: Thanks, although the above code works, when there are more then 1 orders marked as 'Other' for example, your proposed code only shows the latest record. I need to show all for that status.

Comment: Oops! Sorry totally just an error with the output loop. See Edit.

Comment: Still unable to get the expected outcome. See issue above.